# Anyone able to explain how the target property is being used in this functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks, use-effect

Basically, I used useEffect (react Hooks) to enable closing the menu when clicking outside a div.

I found a method online but just can't wrap my head around how target is being used as a property for the clickHandler.

I know how event.target works when accessing an element via a triggered event but in this context I struggle to follow through why or whatsoever.

Sorry for this noob question, any help is much appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Nav.css';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function Nav({id}) {

    const [hidden, sethidden] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const clickHandler = ({target}) => {
            const container = document.getElementById(`container-${id}`);
            if (container.contains(target))
            return; sethidden(true);
        };

        document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    });

    return (
        <div id={`container-${id}`}>
            {hidden ? null : 
            <nav >
                <ul className='nav-links'>
                    <NavLink to='/howItWorks' 
                        activeStyle={{
                            color: ' coral'
                        }}>
                        <li>How it works</li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/drumMachine' 
                        activeStyle={{
                            color: '#6c8993'
                        }}>
                        <li>Live Drum Machine</li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/howIMadeIt' 
                        activeStyle={{
                            color: '#39a3c6',
                            height: '',
                    
                    }}>
                        <li>How I made it</li>
                    </NavLink>
                </ul>
            </nav>}

            <button onClick={() => sethidden(!hidden)}>{hidden ? 'Get started!' : 'Close'}</button>
            
        </div>  )
}

export default Nav;
```

Comment: Take a look at [MDN - Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you wish to know why {target } exists in the parameters of the `clickHandler`

It's using a method called [destructring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where it's destructuring property `target` out of object `e` directly in the method parameters.

```
  const clickHandler = ({target}) => {
            const container = document.getElementById(`container-${id}`);
            if (container.contains(target))
            return; sethidden(true);
        };
```

is the same as

```
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
            const {target} = e;
            const container = document.getElementById(`container-${id}`);
            if (container.contains(target))
            return; sethidden(true);
        };
```

which is the same as

```
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
            const target = e.target;
            const container = document.getElementById(`container-${id}`);
            if (container.contains(target))
            return; sethidden(true);
        };
```